# Does my money still grow if I have it in Coinbase Vault?

Tags: coinbase.com, investing

I just created a Vault account on my Coinbase account. When the money is deposited into the Vault does it stop growing or will it continue to grow based on the coin?

Comment: Grow in what way? Do you mean like earn interest? Or the USD (or other fiat currency) value of your Bitcoin?

Comment: Coinbase doesn't set the value. If you put one bitcoin in the vault, you'll always only have one bitcoin.

Comment: I mean like will the fiat value grow based on the coin value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of cryptocurrency you deposited into the 'Coinbase Vault' will remain the same (unless there are some fees levied by Coinbase for the storage, etc). So if you put 1 bitcoin in, later you will be able to withdraw 1 bitcoin. The value of that 1 bitcoin (measured in USD) may change during that time, but you will still own the same amount (1 bitcoin).